# I trained my data and obtained a training score of 0.957. Why can't I get the data to provide a prediction even against the same training data?

Tags: svm

I have tried to debug this, but have not made any headway.  Any ideas on how to proceed?  I believe I am invoking everything correctly.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
if _trainWithModel:
        print("Training using model")
        svc = svm.SVC(C=0.001, verbose=10, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.00000001)
        fittedSvc = svc.fit(trainingData.data, trainingData.target)
        print("Scoring training results = ", fittedSvc.score(trainingData.data, trainingData.target))
        print("Sanity check.  Predicting using training data model")
        temp_predictedTarget = fittedSvc.predict(trainingData.data)
        realTarget = np.array([trainingData.target])
        predictedTarget = np.array([temp_predictedTarget])
        print"Prediction results shapes:  trainingData.data=", trainingData.data.shape, ", temp_predictedTarget=", temp_predictedTarget.shape, \
            ", realTarget=", realTarget.shape, ", predictedTarget=", predictedTarget.shape
        print"Prediction sanity checks  predictData.target sum=", sum(trainingData.target), \
            ", temp_predictedTarget sum=", sum(temp_predictedTarget), \
            ", predictedTarget sum=", np.sum(predictedTarget), \
            ", realTarget sum=", np.sum(realTarget)
        confusion = confusion_matrix(trainingData.data, temp_predictedTarget)
        print "Confusion matrix:  \n", confusion
```

Here is the key output from this:

```
Training using model [LibSVM]..
Warning: using -h 0 may be faster
*
optimization finished, #iter = 2430
obj = -4.860000, rho = -1.000054
nSV = 4860, nBSV = 4860
Total nSV = 4860
('Scoring training results = ', 0.95715721363211625)
Sanity check.  Predicting using training data model

Prediction results shapes:  
trainingData.data= (56719L, 108L) , 
temp_predictedTarget= (56719L,) , 
realTarget= (1L, 56719L) , 
predictedTarget= (1L, 56719L)

Prediction sanity checks  
predictData.target sum= 2430.0 , 
temp_predictedTarget sum= 0.0 , 
predictedTarget sum= 0.0 , 
realTarget sum= 2430.0

Confusion matrix:  
[[54289     0]
 [ 2430     0]]
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not being able to predict against your own data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the training data has some noise in it, you don't want a fit of 1.0 because that would mean you've overfit the model to the noise. Instead you want your model to be capable of generalizing so it can make the best possible predictions on new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, and you actually do that correctly. You simply misinterpret the results.

For the target variable, you have `54289` instances encoded with `0` and `2430` encoded with `1`. The classifier does not find a proper separator and simply classifies everything to class `0`.

The obtained score is not misleading. The score is obtained as a fraction of the correct prediction count divided by the total number of predictions. Since the only correctly predicted instance count is the count of the instances labeled with $0$, the formula is simply:

$$\frac{\#zeroes}{\#zeroes + \#ones} = \frac{54289}{54289+2430} = 0.9571572136321163$$

This is clearly shown also in the confusion matrix which you plotted.

On the other hand what you might probably do is to put some more weight on penaly errors. Thus you probably have to play with 'C' parameter from the svm learner, probably by increasing the value of 'C' to much bigger values. It is pretty hard to find a proper value for this parameter, a rule of thumb would be to use first values of the form $10^k$, where $k$ is an integer in $[-7,7]$ and refine around good values.